# import btc electrum wallet into coinomi

Tags: electrum, wallet-import, coinomi

can I import btc electrum wallet into my [coinomi](https://coinomi.com/) mulit-currency wallet app?

They both use electrum servers and they both have seeds so it looks like they are a similar kind of wallet.

In electrum I have the option

```
File/Save Copy
```

This looks like it saves a file with no extension next to

```
/home/username/.electrum/wallets/default_wallet
```

Could I import this into Coinomi via

```
(Coinomi app) /Settings/Restore Wallet/RESTORE A WALLET

enter my electrum seed / recovery phrase and password...
```

Without loosing my coins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `electrum` seed is not compatible with BIP32/[BIP44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki), which is essentially what [Coinomi](https://coinomi.com/) implements, so the answer to your question is no, you cannot import your `electrum` seed into `coinomi` at the moment, although this might be possible in the future.

Comment: keep up the good work